# Using custom formatter classes with Python's logging.config module

Tags: python, logging, python-2.7

I have the following logging class, which works fine when assigned as a formatter in code. It extends an existing formatter by prepending a string to the start of the message to be logged, to help show the importance of the message. (I don't just use `%(levelname)s` in the format string because I don't want to show DEBUG or INFO prefixes.)

```
class PrependErrorLevelFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def __init__(self, default):
        self._default_formatter = default
    def format(self, record):
        if record.levelno == logging.WARNING:
            record.msg = "[WARNING] " + record.msg
        elif record.levelno == logging.ERROR:
            record.msg = "[ERROR] " + record.msg
        elif record.levelno == logging.CRITICAL:
            record.msg = "[CRITICAL] " + record.msg
        return self._default_formatter.format(record)
```

Now I want to be able to assign it via a configuration file loaded in by logging.config.fileConfig(). I have tried syntax like this:

```
[formatter_PrependErrorLevelFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s  %(message)s
datefmt=%X
class=PrependErrorLevelFormatter
```

Unfortunately I get errors resolving this class:

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\config.py", line 70, in fileConfig
    formatters = _create_formatters(cp)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\config.py", line 127, in _create_formatters
    c = _resolve(class_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\config.py", line 88, in _resolve
    found = __import__(used)
ImportError: No module named PrependErrorLevelFormatter
```

I have tried prefixing the class name with the name of the module it is in, but get the same error. And even if it could resolve the class, it will probably not work due to the extra default formatter argument I need to provide.

How can I achieve the result I want using the logging.config system?

Comment: You can use `%(levelname)s` in the format definition (http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes).

Comment: I commented on this in the first paragraph.

Comment: So, is your question answered now?

Comment: Yes, sorry - I meant to click answer as well as upvote! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you are using Python 2.7, you could use dictionary-based configuration using [`dictConfig()`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.dictConfig): this is more flexible than `fileConfig()`, as it allows use of arbitrary callables as factories to return e.g. handlers, formatters, or filters.

If you *have* to use `fileConfig()`, you'll have to construct a callable which takes `format` and `datefmt` string values and returns an instance of your class. The `class` value just needs to resolve to a callable, not an actual class. Here's a setup that works: In [this gist](https://gist.github.com/1782815), I have a file `custfmt.py` which contains the formatter definition, and a script `fcfgtest.py` which uses it via `fileConfig()`. Just get the files into a scratch directory and run `fcfgtest.py` - you should see output like this:

```
20:17:59 debug message
20:17:59 info message
20:17:59 [WARNING] warning message
20:17:59 [ERROR] error message
20:17:59 [CRITICAL] critical message
```

which appears to be what you need.

Note that you can use an alternative design for your formatter, which should do the same job:

```
class AltCustomFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record):
        if record.levelno in (logging.WARNING,
                              logging.ERROR,
                              logging.CRITICAL):
            record.msg = '[%s] %s' % (record.levelname, record.msg)
        return super(AltCustomFormatter , self).format(record)
```

To use this, you don't need a separate factory function, so you can just use

```
class=custfmt.AltCustomFormatter
```

instead of

```
class=custfmt.factory
```

and it should work - it did for me when I tested just now using Python 2.7.1 :-)

Comment: Ok, I think it's working. I had to remember to prefix the class name with the name of the file it's in, but it seems to find it now. (Whereas this didn't work for my previous solution - strange!)