# How to only log a certain levelname python logging

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-logging

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler,errorHandler,debugHandler

[formatters]
keys=errorFormatter,debugFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler,errorHandler,debugHandler
propagate=0

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=debugFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_errorHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=ERROR
formatter=errorFormatter
args=('errors.log',)

[handler_debugHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=debugFormatter
args=('debugs.log',)

[formatter_errorFormatter]
style={
format=
    {asctime} - {name} - {levelname} - line {lineno} - {message}
datefmt=%d/%m/%y - %H:%M:%S

[formatter_debugFormatter]
style={
format={asctime} - {name} - {levelname} - {message}
datefmt=%d/%m/%y - %H:%M:%S
```

If I have a config file like above, how can I access the `debugHandler` so that I can do like `debugHandler.addFilter(my_custom_filter)`?

I'm essentially trying to make it so that `DEBUG` messages are sent to `debugs.log` and `ERROR` messages are sent to `errors.log`, but currently `ERROR` messages are also sent to `debugs.log` which I don't want. Now, based on [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50381501/python-logging-handler-only-log-level-log-less-than-error), this is achievable via filters but in order to add a filter I need a `logging.Handler` object and I don't know how to obtain one.

Thanks in advance :~)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, you would need a filter on your debug_handler, however you cannot add Filters via a [fileConfig](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.fileConfig).

From the docs:

> The fileConfig() API is older than the dictConfig() API and does not
>   provide functionality to cover certain aspects of logging. For
>   example, you cannot configure Filter objects, which provide for
>   filtering of messages beyond simple integer levels, using
>   fileConfig(). If you need to have instances of Filter in your logging
>   configuration, you will need to use dictConfig(). Note that future
>   enhancements to configuration functionality will be added to
>   dictConfig(), so it’s worth considering transitioning to this newer
>   API when it’s convenient to do so.

So consider using [dictConfig](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.dictConfig) (there shouldn't be any reason for you not to switch to `dictConfig`, regardless of your configuration, as it is better, newer, more flexible, and the one where all the future good stuff will be added).

So your config, transitioned to `dictConfig` would look something like this (this can be pasted and tested as-is):

```
import logging
from logging import config

class FileFilter:
    """Allow only LogRecords whose severity levels are below ERROR."""

    def __call__(self, log):
        if log.levelno < logging.ERROR:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0


logging_config = {
    'version': 1,
    'formatters': {
        'error_formatter': {
            'format': '{asctime} - {name} - {levelname} - line {lineno} - {message}',
            'style': '{',
            'datefmt': '%d/%m/%y - %H:%M:%S',
        },
        'debug_formatter': {
            'format': '{asctime} - {name} - {levelname} - {message}',
            'style': '{',
            'datefmt': '%d/%m/%y - %H:%M:%S',
        },
    },
    'filters': {
        'file_filter': {
            '()': FileFilter,
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console_handler': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'debug_formatter',
        },
        'error_handler': {
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'formatter': 'debug_formatter',
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filename': 'errors.log',
        },
        'debug_handler': {
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'formatter': 'debug_formatter',
            'filters': ['file_filter'],
            'filename': 'debug.log',
        },
    },
    'root': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'handlers': ['console_handler', 'error_handler', 'debug_handler'],
    },
}

config.dictConfig(logging_config)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# these get logged to the console and only to the debugs.log file
# if you want just the debug messages logged to the file, adjust the filter
logger.debug('this is a debug message')
logger.info('this is an info message')
logger.warning('this is a warning message')

# this get logged to the console and only to the errors.log file
logger.error('this is an error message')
logger.critical('this is a critical message')
```

Which will output:

```
27/09/19 - 07:52:44 - __main__ - DEBUG - this is a debug message  # also to debug.log
27/09/19 - 07:52:44 - __main__ - INFO - this is an info message  # also to debug.log
27/09/19 - 07:52:44 - __main__ - WARNING - this is a warning message  # also to debug.log
27/09/19 - 07:52:44 - __main__ - ERROR - this is an error message  # also to errors.log but not to debug.log
27/09/19 - 07:52:44 - __main__ - CRITICAL - this is a critical message  # also to errors.log but not to debug.log
```

If you, for some mysterious reason (I can't see any) insist on using the older API, `fileConfig`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212228/using-custom-formatter-classes-with-pythons-logging-config-module) which uses custom formatters, which achieve the same thing, without filters.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response! Just a small 'issue', whilst it does work as expected, I don't get the extra line before the `logging.error` which I'd like. I don't mind whether the newline is before or after the log, but would appreciate it if you edited so the newline was included. (I did try adding `\n` but it appears to get stripped)

Comment: @TizzySaurus I was on my phone so I'll reply properly this time. So the newline character was added manually for you to see the split between all the logs that will be written to `debug.log` vs all the logs that will be written to `error.log`. I've edited the post and removed it. In order for you to achieve that functionality (which I recommend against) you would need to use a custom `Formatter`. However, that is beyond the scope of this question, so please consider asking another question and I'll answer there, **however** I recommend against doing that, because the console will be a mess.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I'll leave it as it is as I can now see how it would probably be more messy than useful.